# How can I re-write $H(X_1,X_2)+H(X_2,X_3)+H(X_1,X_3)$ using $\sum$ notation?

Tags: summation

How can I re-write $H(X_1,X_2)+H(X_2,X_3)+H(X_1,X_3)$ using $\sum$ notation?

Also how can I re-write $H(X_1,X_2,X_3)+H(X_1,X_2,X_4)+H(X_1,X_3,X_4)+ H(X_2,X_3,X_4)$ using $\sum$ notation?

Is there any way to generalize a sum so I can find any sum even if I want pairs of two , or pairs of 3 or pairs of any number?

Is $\sum H(X_i,X_j, j>i)$ correct? If yes what limits the sum will have?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sum\limits_{1 \leq i < j \leq 3}H(X_i,X_j)$.

Comment: Is there any way to generalize the above?? I mean I want this sum when I am working with n = 3 (H(X1,X2,X3)).

If I am working with n = 4 (H(X1,X2,X3,X4)) then I want the sum H(X1,X2,X3)+H(X1,X2,X4)+H(X1,X3,X4)+H(X2,X3,X4).

Is there any way to generalize this sum for all n?

Comment: $1 \leq i < j < k \leq 4$.. in general $1 \leq i_1 < i_2 <  \dots <i_t \leq n$..

Comment: Is the above a triple sum??

Comment: $\sum\limits_{1 \leq i < j < k\leq 4}H(X_i,X_j,X_k)$.